# configuration of secondary namenode in hadoop 2.6

Tags: apache, hadoop

I set the secondary namenode with this line in `hadoop-env.sh`

```
HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS=<hostname>
```

which seems to be wrong, because the master is using `0.0.0.0`. Should I use a different address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS is used to set command line properties for the secondary namenode java process. Like below

```
HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"
```

To start secondary namenode you need to maintain core-site.xml with namenode details and just start the secondary namenode. If you are still facing issues update your logs and config folders